# Apache-Camel: How to put more than one Ical File in exchange

Tags: apache-camel, exchange-server, icalendar

i have a processor which puts an unmarshaled ical file in a custom object. After this a list of my object is saved into exchange.
After this i need to put a second ical into exchange. Problem is that i cant use "from" two times in a route. How can i solve this?

Code for processing one ical is the following:

```
from("file://src/test/resources?fileName=Calendar.ics&delete=false&noop=true")
.unmarshal("ical")
.process(icsToBeanProcessor)
.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can improve the design a bit. Instead of specifying filenames use a directory instead. Process all files present in the directory and set them in header properties. Something like

```
from("file://src/test/resources?delete=false&noop=true")
.unmarshal("ical")
.process(icsToBeanProcessor) // in your icsToBeanProcessor set a header property as content.fileName as the output of your unmarshaller bean
.end();
```

Also you can be more specific by using a regex for specifying filenames. For your case pick only those files which ends with "ics". See http://camel.apache.org/file.html for more details.